# Struts Validation - Combining requiredif and mask

Tags: java, validation, struts, mask

I have a requirement in my app where a field is required on certain conditions and then that field should match a particular pattern.
Is there a way I can combine the requiredif and mask conditions?
I am on struts 1.

Here's the validation.xml

```
<form-validation>
  <global>
    <constant>
      <constant-name>char</constant-name>
      <constant-name>^[a-zA-Z]*$</constant-name>
    </constant>
  </global>

  <formset>
    <form name="myform">
      <field property="city" depends="requiredif">
        <arg0 key="city"/>
        <var>
          <var-name>field[0]</var-name>
          <var-value>state</var-value>
        </var>
        <var>
          <var-name>fieldTest[0]</var-name>
          <var-value>EQUAL</var-value>
        </var>
        <var>
          <var-name>fieldValue[0]</var-name>
          <var-value>SEATTLE</var-value>
        </var>
      </field>
    </form>
  </formset>
</form-validation>
```

How do I add a mask condition so that it is checked only if the above condition is true?

Thanks

Sahil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, don't; leave complex validations to Java code. The overhead of maintaining complex validations in the XML file isn't worth the effort.

"requiredif" was deprecated and should be replaced with "validwhen", btw. You can [create (relatively) complex validations with "validwhen"](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/faqs/validator.html#Designing_Complex_Validations_with_validwhen), but... ew. Much cleaner to do in Java.